# PDF Cross-Reference Stream

Tags: pdf, cross-reference

I know that 0002 is object's number in pdf file. Last column's(from 01 to 07) name was "index" (In pdf reference document ) But what does 01,02,03,04,05,06 and 07 mean? Where they are pointing in object 2? I didn't get it.

Here is the Cross Reference Stream :

```
    stream 01 0E8A 0 % Entry for object 2 (0x0E8A = 3722) 
    SyntaxCHAPTER 3 114
    02 0002 00 % Entry for object 3 (in object stream 2, index 0) 
    02 0002 01 % Entry for object 4 (in object stream 2, index 1) 
    02 0002 02 % … 
    02 0002 03 
    02 0002 04 
    02 0002 05 
    02 0002 06 
    02 0002 07 % Entry for object 10 (in object stream 2, index 7) 
    01 1323 0 % Entry for object 11 (0x1323 = 4899) 
    endstream
```

and here is the second object in the example pdf document:

```
    2 0 obj       % The object stream, at offset 3722 
    <</Length     ... 
    /N 8          % This stream contains 8 objects. 
    /First 47     % The stream-offset of the first object 
    >> 
    stream 
    3 0 4 50 5 72 …    % The numbers and stream-offsets of the 8 objects 
    <</Type /StructTreeRoot    % This is object 3. 
    /K 4 0 R  
    /RoleMap 5 0 R  
    /ClassMap 6 0 R  
    /ParentTree 7 0 R  
    /ParentTreeNextKey 8  
    >>  
    << /S /Workbook     % This is object 4 (K value from StructTreeRoot). 
    /P 8 0 R  
    /K 9 0 R  
    >>  
    <</Workbook /Div     % This is object 5 (RoleMap). 
    /Worksheet /Sect  
    /TextBox /Figure  
    /Shape /Figure 
    >> 
    … % Objects 6 through 10 are defined here. 
    endstream 
    endobj
```

Comment: *But what does 01,02,03,04,05,06 and 07 mean? Where they are pointing in object 2?* - its the index in the list `3 0 4 50 5 72 …    % The numbers and stream-offsets of the 8 objects` of pairs of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the [PDF 32000 standard](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

According to the cross-reference streams' chapter, there're three types of entries that presents in xref streams.

These entries (with first byte = 02) tell us that they're located in the compressed stream object #2. Third field makes sense about number of object inside this compressed stream